# Did Facebook Like-Share iframe recently broke?

Tags: facebook

I have had a working Facebook widget (like-share buttons) on my website for long now, but since yesterday they stopped working.

I verified that other sites i know are having the same errors.

Cause of the error is the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header i have in my website.

The problem is: this header never gave any issue with those buttons. Now i see in the console that they throw an error when they try to load a script that is denied from my security headers (as it should be).

Does anyone know if the Facebook team is going to fix this soon, else, does any one know how to replace the Facebook like-share buttons with another equivalent Facebook widjet?

Thanks.